# AttributeError: Can't get attribute '_default_unk_index' on <module 'torchtext.vocab'

Tags: pytorch

I run my code in google colab, but I meet some error.

torch:1.1.0, torchtext:0.4.0, I update them, but it's useless

```
[2019-09-14 02:57:15,574 INFO]  * src vocab size = 49766
[2019-09-14 02:57:15,574 INFO]  * history vocab size = 49766
[2019-09-14 02:57:15,574 INFO]  * tgt vocab size = 49766
[2019-09-14 02:57:15,574 INFO] Building model...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/ReDR/train.py", line 109, in <module>
    main(opt)
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/ReDR/train.py", line 41, in main
    single_main(opt, -1)
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/ReDR/onmt/train_single.py", line 86, in main
    model = build_model(model_opt, opt, fields, checkpoint)
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/ReDR/onmt/model_builder.py", line 235, in build_model
    vocab = torch.load(opt.drqa_vocab_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 387, in load
    return _load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 574, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()
AttributeError: Can't get attribute '_default_unk_index' on <module 'torchtext.vocab' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchtext/vocab.py'>
```

I will appreciate any help from you!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same exact same issue, solution provided in https://github.com/ZJULearning/ReDR/issues/3

edit ReDR/onmt/model_builder.py

add

```
from torchtext import vocab
try:
    vocab._default_unk_index
except AttributeError:
    def _default_unk_index():
        return 0
    vocab._default_unk_index = _default_unk_index
```

That should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of torchtext used while *saving* the vocabulary and then *loading* the same vocabulary. This [torchtext github issue](https://github.com/pytorch/text/issues/601) talks about the same issue. The solution is to either downgrade to the torchtext version in which it was saved. Or upgrade the torchtext version, recreate the vocab pickle file and then use it.

### Scenario 1

- vocab saved with torchtext 0.3.1
- vocab loaded using torchtext 0.4.0
- Solution is, downgrade torchtext from 0.4.0 to 0.3.1 and then vocab loading should work

  ```
  pip install torchtext==0.3.1
  ```

For me this solution worked.

### Scenario 2

- vocab saved with torchtext 0.3.1
- vocab loaded using torchtext 0.4.0
- Solution is, upgrade torchtext from 0.3.1 to 0.4.0 and then save the vocab again using new torchtext. Now the loading should correctly work.

  ```
  pip install torchtext==0.4.0
  ```